# How do I grab screenshots from a YouTube?

Tags: discussion, support

I want to post a screen shot from a YouTube, in my [question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3035/was-any-first-stage-recovery-system-tested-on-spacex-falcon-9-flight-seven) but short of Print Screen to an editor, I do not know how to do a screen grab from YouTube.

Any well known, simple ways? I know how to download the FLV file, but not how to get one image or two.

I am running Winders 7 Pro 64 bit, and use Firefox 25 browser, usually.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using OS X, (which you probably aren't since you reference print screen), the system comes with a handy little shortcut: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> gives you a nice little screenshot-taker-draggy thingy.

Comment: On Windows, and could do the simple Print Screen, dump it into mspaint.exe, crop and go, but was hoping there was a more clever approach.

Comment: @geoffc A little late for this, but you can also press the Win key and type the first couple of letters of "Snipping tool" and when it comes up hit Enter. Snipping tool allows you to do a click and drag capture of a section of the screen.

Comment: Of course, on Windows 10 it is now (as of 2018) being phased out for Snip & Sketch.

Answer (score 2):

Did it the hard way, with Fn, Alt Print Screen (which is shared with my End button, thus the need for the Fn button.  Alt modifies the screen grab to only the current active window instead of the entire desktop).  Opened mspaint.exe, Ctrl-V to paste.  Then the crop tool to select my segment, Ctrl-C to copy.  Ctrl-N for a new image, Ctrl-V to paste, Ctrl-S to save.

Then edited my question.

Oh well, hoped there was an easier way.

Comment: This whole process should take 10 seconds or 20 seconds.